# Listen to RSS Feeds on Update C#

Tags: c#, rss

I am retrieving data from this RSS feed.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string url = "https://myanimelist.net/rss/news.xml";
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    foreach (var item in feed.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
    }
}
```

It gets the latest news posts. However, how can I "listen" to the feed so I know when a new post is updated?

Answer (score 0):

you can't really listen, you have to keep going back and getting the feed to see if it has changed.  This is called "Polling"

Comment: But is the whole point of an RSS feed not the Aggregator concept?

Comment: yes, what RSS does is provide a concise standard format that an aggregator can use to check for new content.    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS and specifically,  "The RSS reader checks the user's feeds regularly for new information and can automatically download it"

Comment: Yeah, what I'm confused about is how do I use this aggregator in C#. As for as I can tell I have to run my own timer.

Comment: yes, you can use a timer, there are also libraries like hangfire and quartz.net